# Why is the "I" in "Indigenous crisis" capitalized?

Tags: terminology, capitalization

This is [from today's Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/aug/02/maori-land-rights-leader-calls-on-jacinda-ardern-to-recognise-indigenous-crisis):

[image]

I am wondering why the newspaper capitalized the "I" in "Indigenous".

According to Lexico, *[indigenous](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/indigenous)* is spelled with a lowercase letter

Comment: You could argue that newspapers often capitalised words headlines but this case would appear to be different. Perhaps, it's a Trumpism feature :)

Comment: Assuming it is deliberate, I would guess it is because it is talking about a specific indigenous people (the Maoris). Perhaps if you write to the Guardian they might send you a copy of their style guide.

Comment: In Canada anyway, the native people are currently referred to with the proper noun *Indigenous*. While it's also a word, in this context it's a name. As a proper noun, it's capitalized.

Comment: @JasonBassford As Mari-Lou has mentioned,  "Indigenous" here seems like an adjective to modify "crisis", not a noun in itself. Even if "Indigenous" is a noun adjunct, it still seems strange to me. Less strange would seem something like "Guy calls on prime minister to acknowledge the Indigenous", where "Indigenous" clearly is a noun. Even as a compound noun and "indigenous" being a noun adjunct, you'd think that the entire compound noun should be capitalized.

Comment: @Zebrafish You would say the Inuit crisis and you would say the Maori crisis. The Indigenous crisis is exactly the same. If you've lived in a place where it's not only common but actually *mandated* by the government, then it's not unusual at all.

Comment: @Zebrafish the fact that some native species of plants and animals can't compete with introduced species is an indigenous crisis (with a small i), but not what the headline is referring to!

Comment: @nnnnnn at least a quick-reference version is online  For hints see under [*aborigines*](https://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-a) as well as under [*Indigenous...*](https://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-i)

Comment: @Zebrafish on the contrary, capital "Indigenous", lower-case "crisis" makes it clear that "Indigenous" isn't an adjective, i.e. hints at a crisis affecting the indigenous (people)

Comment: @ChrisH Reminds me of the crisis among the Homeless, or among the Unemployed, or among the Tired and the Poor  yearning to be Free. :)

Answer (score 7):

It's similar to the use of the words [Aboriginal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aboriginal_Australians) and [Squatter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squatting_(Australia)) in Australia.

The word [aboriginal](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/aboriginal) with a lower case 'a' means 'indiginous' or 'original inhabitant' but 'Aboriginal' with an upper case 'A' came to refer to people descended from the indigenous people of Australia {with all the attendant bias and abuse that accompanied colonialism}.

The word 'squatter' with a lower case 's' on the other hand means someone who occupies a property or piece of land either illegally or without legal title of any sort. However the word 'Squatter' with an upper case 'S' has come to mean a large, wealthy landowner. I understand that 'Squatter' meaning a landowner is often written with a lower case 's' but whenever 'Squatter' appears in the middle of a sentence it will refer to a large landowner, not a homeless person occupying a building illegally.

Answer (score 5):

It's capitalized to indicate a specific group of people, i.e. the "Indigenous" Maori's.  "Maori" also capitalized as to indicate their race of people are "Maori".

Comment: Does New Zealand distinguish between indigenous and non-indigenous Maori?

Comment: We do not normally distinguish between the two. From our point of view all Maori are the indigenous people of New Zealand. I am not aware of any Maori that are not indigenous.

Answer (score 0):

"Indigenous" is capitalized in that article because the author viewed it as a proper noun or adjective (both of which are capitalized in English).

Unfortunately, there aren't clear criteria for determining when a noun or adjective in English "counts as" a proper noun/adjective vs. common noun/adjective. You just have to learn how each word is used. (Sometimes there are differences in usage between different publishers.) Some words can be used either way, with a lowercase or capital letter depending on the meaning.